# Why are bootstrap options not being set?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am trying to supply runtime options for some properties to a contenteditable div and use JS to show it. For testing, I have supplied some data propertirs.

HTML form:

```
<form id="form-email-preview" style="margin-top: 24px;">
    <div id="main-container" class="hidden" style="border: 1px solid orange; padding: 6px;  border-radius: 8px;">
        <div id="subject-container" class='hidden' style="display: inline; padding-left: 4px;">
            <span>Subject: </span><input id="subject" type="text" value="Manuscript Request" />
        </div>
        <div id="mail-container" contenteditable data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="right" data-title ="Required field" style="display: inline-block"></div><br/>
        <p id="buttons" class="hidden">
            <input type='button' id='send-email' class='btn btn-custom-success' value='Send Email' /><span>   </span>
            <button id='cancel-email' class = 'btn btn-danger'>Cancel</button>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="current-row" class="hidden"></div>
    <input id="current-checkbox" type="checkbox" class="hidden" />
    <input id="current-tr" type="number" class="hidden" />
</form>
```

Although the popover does show the data -props, the runtime options are not displayed.

[image]

JavaScript

```
$('[data-toggle=popover]').popover();

,,,

$("#send-email").on('mousedown', function (e) {
//$("#form-email-preview").on('submit', function (e) { //doesn't fire?
//    e.preventDefault();
    var mc = $("#mail-container");
    //debugger
    if (!$.trim(mc.val())) {
        mc.popover({content: 'Please fill in this field.', placement: 'top', trigger: 'focus'});
        mc.popover('show');
        mc.focus();
        return false;
    }
    var data = {};
    data.action = "manuscript-request-email";
    data["writers-id"] = $("#writer-id").val();
    data["account-id"] = localStorage.getItem("account-id");
    data.subject = $("#subject").val();
    data.body = $("#mail-container").html();
    ajax('post', 'php/writers.php', data, sentEmail);
    function sentEmail(result) {
        console.log("email-res=" + result);
        return2table();
    }
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of searching and experimentation, the following worked for me:

```
    var mc = $("#mail-container");
    if (!$.trim(mc.text())) {
        mc.popover("destroy").popover({ content: "Please fill out this field", placement: 'right' });
        mc.popover('show');
        mc.focus();
        return false;
    }
```